# clean DerivedData caches in xcode -to get rid of error in device

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When trying to run the app (that did worked before) on device i get error :

```
No such file or directory (/Users/ran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName...)
```

I have also read to clean this path :

```
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

but i cant find it in my mac- it says i dont have this path !

Any idea how to solve that problem ? (restarting xcode or clean  did not worked )

Comment: check out Xcode => Preferences => Locations  @Rant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open "Products" group in XCode, and right click .app file and click Show in Finder, this will be in the place which you want.

Comment: thanks . it takes me to "Release-iphoneos" , what do i have to clear from that in order to get rid of the problem ?